# Sanitize POST htmlentities or plus stripslashes and strip_tags

Tags: php, security

As always I start this saying that I am learning. 
I saw in several books and even here, that a lot of user when we are talking about sanitize, for example, Form>Input>Submit, they use

```
function sanitizeexample($param)
{
    $param = stripslashes($param);
    $param = strip_tags($param);
    $param = htmlentities($param);
    return $param;
}

$name = sanitizeexample($_POST['name']);
```

Instead of **JUST**:

```
function sanitizeexample($param)
{
    $param = htmlentities($param);
    return $param;
}

$name = sanitizeexample($_POST['name']);
```

So here the question. Do *stripslashes() and strip_tags()* provide something else regarding to security? Or it´s enough with *htmlentities()*.

And I´m asking JUST to know which is the best to use.

Comment: One mangles your input in inappropriate ways, one mangles your input in more inappropriate ways. “Sanitising” input as an approach to injection issues is misguided, entirely the wrong thing, and it's a shame people are still talking about it who should know better. To protect against HTML-injection you do `htmlspecialchars` *at template output time*, not against anything in $_POST. Other forms of escaping (eg SQL) need to be used at the appropriate output generation time, *not* against input. Background http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42498

Comment: @bobince Thanks! Remember that I am learning and it´s really difficult when you find many different views. So... I should use htmlspecialchars for POST+echo and htmlspecialchars and real_escape_string for MySQL queries? Is that correct?! Thanks! :D

Comment: I would consider validation over sanitization in this case

Comment: Yes, use `echo htmlspecialchars(...)` for outputting into an HTML template (you can define a function like `h()` to do it so you don't have to type as much), and for putting a string in an SQL query it would be `mysql_real_escape_string`, except that generally it's easier and more maintainable to use parameterised queries (for which you will need mysqli or PDO) to avoid having to stitch queries together at all. Input validation is a good idea for various application-specific purposes but it is not the answer to injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

Whether `strip_tags()` provides a value-add is dependent on your particular use case. If you `htmlentities()` a string that contains html tags, you're going to get the raw html content escaped and rendered on the page. The example you give is probably making the assumption that this is *not* what you want, and so by doing `strip_tags()` first, html tags are removed.

`stripslashes` is the inverse to `addslashes`. In modern (PHP >= 5.4) PHP code, this is not necessary. On legacy systems, with `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled, user input from request variables are automagically escaped with `addslashes` so as to make them "safe" for direct use in database queries. This has widely been considered a Bad Idea (because it's not actually safe, for many reasons) and `magic_quotes` has been removed. Accordingly, you would now not normally need to `stripslashes()` user input. (Whether you actually need to is going to be dependent on PHP version and ini settings.)

(Note that you would still need to properly escape any content going into your database, but that is better done with parameterized queries or database-specific escaping functions, both of which are outside the scope of this question.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, for MySQL (in my case) I´m using real_escape_string(). So, if I am understanding, I just need to use htmlentities() since it "do the work" of strip_tags() and with a good configuration (magic_quotes_gpc) stripslashes it is not necessary. Am I right? I am learning and I am trying to do it well. Thanks again!

Comment: @Peter `htmlentities()` does not "do the work" of `strip_tags()`. They have two completely different purposes, and which one(s) you use depends entirely on what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your goals:

- if you're getting user's data passed from `html` form - you should
  definitely apply `strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']))` approach to
  sanitize possible insecure and excessive data.
- if you are receiving uploaded user's file content and need to save
  content formatting - you have to consider how to safely process and
  store such files making some specific(selective) sanitizing

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a basic summarize (just to understand) is it correct for POST and ECHO htmlentities+strip_tags+trim and for POST for MySQL htmlentities+real_escape_string or am I missing something?

Comment: `htmlentities` is useful when you want to encode html tags into special chars. Example: I'm decided to store some encoded html markup in database, and then I can retrieve it and decode it with htmlspecialchars_decode  for generating content on frontend

Comment: @Peter, real_escape_string, I suppose you meant `mysql_real_escape_string`. It definitely should be utilized to prevent SQL injenctions. But now it's deprecated since php 5.5. I recommend you to use PDO